# How to configure APT Pinning to prevent installation of bash Release Candidate

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I'm currently using a **Debian/testing** distribution on my amd64 desktop. On this distribution, the latest version for `bash` package is 5.2~rc2-2, see https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/bash

I don't want to install RC (Release Candidate) version for `bash` because this package is built with DEBUG flag, see [https://sources.debian.org/src/bash/5.2~rc2-2/configure.ac/#L43-L45](https://sources.debian.org/src/bash/5.2%7Erc2-2/configure.ac/#L43-L45).

I configure [APT Pinning](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/apt/apt_preferences.5.en.html) for `bash` to prevent installation of 5.2-rc* version (set `Pin-Priority` to - 1). File `/etc/apt/preferences.d/10-bash` :

```
Package: bash
Pin: version 5.2~rc*
Pin-Priority: -1
```

APT Policy for `bash` is OK :

```bash
$ apt-cache policy bash
bash:
  Installed: 5.1-6.1
  Candidate: 5.1-6.1
  Version table:
     5.2~rc2-2 -1
        990 http://debian.proxad.net/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.1-6.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I would like to use APT Pinning for `bash` **for ALL RC version** (not only 5.2-rc) :

```
Package: bash
Pin: version *rc*
Pin-Priority: -1
```

but with this pattern `*rc*`, it does not work :

```bash
$ apt-cache policy bash
bash:
  Installed: 5.1-6.1
  Candidate: 5.2~rc2-2
  Version table:
     5.2~rc2-2 990
        990 http://debian.proxad.net/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.1-6.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**How to use pattern/glob for version with APT Pinning ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`apt_preferences` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/apt/apt_preferences.5.en.html), **regular expressions need to be surrounded by slashes**.

If I correct my file for APT Pinning (prevent installation of RC version for bash), it works !

```
/etc/apt/preferences.d/10-bash: 

Package: bash
Pin: version /rc/
Pin-Priority: -1
```

```bash
$ apt-cache policy bash
bash:
  Installed: 5.1-6.1
  Candidate: 5.1-6.1
  Version table:
     5.2~rc2-2 -1
        990 http://debian.proxad.net/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.1-6.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```